# Win32com Outlook Body Properties Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

While trying to retrieve the body of an outlook email message with the following code, I get

```
com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)
```

Each of the `print(message.<properties>)` work, except the `Body` property

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.gencache.ensureDispatch("Outlook Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

actionItems = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = actionItems.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
print(message.Subject)
print(message.Body)   -
print(message.Count)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What folder is that? Items in it may not be emails like tasks/appts which only [Mailitem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304.aspx) maintains a `Body` property.

Comment: I wasn't able to post the following as a comment; bug in SO perhaps, so I post here: Have you tried 'print(message.Class)'? The type of item determines the interface so you need to ensure that type supports what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry - it's the "Inbox"....

Comment: May have found an answer, but can't test this until I'm back to work:  https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-win32/13535/

Answer (score 2):

I also had these errors relating to win32com object trying to access values that were not available. The errors such as:

```
$ pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
$ pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467259, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

Are dependant on what unavailable data you are trying to access. i.e.

```
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6).SenderName
```

Will result in:

```
$ pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

And:

```
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6).SenderName.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

Will result in:

```
$ pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467259, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

I found my error was due to an anti-virus add-in on my outlook account blocking the com object from accessing sensitive permission data, such as email addresses, body etc.

My fix:

In outlook 2016: go to:

File >> Options >> Add-ins > "Manage: COM Add-ins" >> Go : untick any antivirus software, in my case in was Symantec Endpoint.

The error disappeared. Hope this helps anyone.