# How to read the body of an outlook email using Python / Win32Client?

Tags: python, win32com

How can I read the body of an outlook email using python? The first code below allows me to access the folder but it continues to return the message subject only. I simply need the body of the message.

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import os
import email
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Eres")
message = inbox.items

for message in inbox.Items:
        if message.unread == True:
    
         print(message)
```

This code below does not work at all and generates the following error..

---

com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
16
17 message = messages.GetLast()
---> 18 body_content = message.body

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in **getattr**(self, attr)
514                         debug_attr_print("Getting property Id 0x%x from OLE object" % retEntry.dispid)
515                         try:
--> 516                                 ret = self.*oleobj*.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
517                         except pythoncom.com_error as details:
518                                 if details.hresult in ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT:

com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import os
import email
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Eres")
messages = inbox.Items

message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
```

Comment: It isn’t guaranteed that `message` is a `MailItem` object, so maybe check that `message.Class` is 43 (constant olMail). Also (and this may not make a difference) try using `Body` with an uppercase ‘B’.

Comment: Hey DS_London, thank you for replying. I chcked class and it is 43 and I have tried Body with the uppercase. It works fine on my personal computer so I think this is a firewall issue on my work computer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)"
This is a security issue.  Likely cause by your antivirus.
Solution: [Win32com Outlook Body Properties Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013632/win32com-outlook-body-properties-error)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32009466)